# Jquery multi css using variables

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with this jquery css:

Like this it works in all browsers but ie9:

```
  $(".%id%faderbox").css({
    "background-image": "url("+bgimage+")",
    "padding": "%id=xtrapadding%px",
    "height": dooheight,
    "width": doowidth,
    "border": doofaderborder
 });
```

dooheight and doowidth are variables declared further up the page, and always return ie: 133px

note: the px on the end.
note: not encloded like: "133px"

now the issue with ie9 seems to be that it does not like the width and height values without the enclosing qoutes ""

So.. ok i thought, i will just do this for example:

```
"width": '"' + doowidth + '"',
```

But this does not work in any browser, even though an alert test clearly shows the value of doowidth now returns: "133px" instead of 133px

hard coding: "width": "133px", works in all browsers including ie 9

I cant understand why it breaks in all browsers with:

```
"width": '"' + doowidth + '"',
```

Comment: I think just writing the variable name adds the " implicitly. Ni idea why this is not working in IE9 though.

Comment: Hi, the %id=xtrapadding% and %id% stuff are just variables in the program this is designed for. they have been checked though and all return correctly, its just the width and height ie9 does not like not to be enclosed in qoutes. Like i say, if i switch those width and height vars for explicit eg "133px" it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does this `%id` and `%id=xtrapadding%` nonsense come from?

And there's no use adding quotes to the strings. They're already strings. The quotes are part of the syntax you use to delimit string literals: they are not actually in the strings themselves, so adding them is wrong.

It seems to me that, for some reason and in some cases, `doowidth` is not being seen as a string. You can force it to be by appending nothingness. Try this:

```
$(".%id%faderbox").css({
    "background-image": "url("+bgimage+")",
    "padding":          "%id=xtrapadding%px",
    "height":           dooheight + '',
    "width":            doowidth + '',
    "border":           doofaderborder + ''
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak Geret'kal i see where you are coming from with the quotes. But this is producing an even stranger effect in ie9. in ie9 doowidth and dooheight now return 0px, whilst all other browsers return the correct value, you can see an illustration of this in action here: http://www.garysimpson.co.uk/testingsite/  even if you dont have ie9, trust me those values i have appended are returning 0px.

Comment: @user692790: I don't really _trust_ you, since you've run into problems. :) Anyway, I believe you're heading in the right direction. Track the value and type of the variables as they change through your script code.

Comment: @user692790: Can you try doing the DOM removal of the images _after_ calculating `doowidth` and `dooheight` from `FArray`? And use their real `.height()` and `.width()` properties rather than relying on HTML attributes.

Comment: I will try that. I was just realizing that ie9 is not getting the value from the way i am currently calculating width and height: [code]
   
    var dooheight = 0;
    $.each(FArray, function(index, height) {
    if($(height).attr("height") > dooheight){
    dooheight = $(height).attr("height");
    }
 });
 dooheight = dooheight +"px"; // add the px for ie[/code]

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Yep using the real height in that function apeezed ie9, thank you..! Just a little more cleaning up to do as there are still some breakages in ie9, but i am sure ill get them in a few moments. Cheers..!

Comment: @user692790: No problem (btw, it's "appeased").

Answer (score -1):

try using single quotes

`'"' + doowidth + '"'`

Comment: Sorry if i am missing something, but i am sure that is what i posted i have already done.

Comment: oops sorry. ok can you check if this works at your end > http://jsfiddle.net/69HrJ/ . I tested it on IE9 and it works for me.

Comment: We have it nailed in the above post, but thanks for trying to help, really.